# Using vim and Caffeine on the same machine

Tags: key-bindings

### Background

I work at a research laboratory and use three different OS's daily. On the Windows and Mac machines I make use of [Caffeine](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/caffeine/) to keep those machines from enabling the screensaver while I work on a different machine (Linux doesn't have this problem). It's very annoying to have to log in again when I switch back.

### Problem

When vim or gvim are in insert mode, the character `<F15>` sporadically appears in the document. I tracked it back to Caffeine after a bit of research. The website for Caffeine states that the software works by occasionally simulating a `<F15>` key press event:

> Of all the key presses available, F15 is probably the least intrusive (I've never seen a PC keyboard with that key!), and least likely to interfere with your work.

So Caffeine is the obvious culprit. However, I still prefer to use my favorite text editor on all three machines, and don't intend to change that just to accommodate using Caffeine.

### Question

**Is there something I can put in my `vimrc` to make vim ignore `<F15>` key press events?**

---

### Edit For Clarity

I can't disable the screensaver timeout; it is set by the IT department for security purposes. So with the Caffeine work-around, in order to remain compliant, I have to manually lock my machines when I step away from my desk. That's not so bad; but unlocking them every few minutes is.

Also, I didn't write Caffeine, so I don't know why the developer chose to click `<F15>` once a minute. I probably would have done it differently, perhaps with a slight mouse motion or touchpad tap, as @Random832 suggested.

Comment: Why not just disable screensavers/timeout-to-lock on those machines? It'd be a much cleaner solution than to configure vim to work around Caffeine's strange behavior. Or at least make Caffeine simulate something like `<Ctrl>` instead of `<F15>`.

Comment: @Ruslan The point of using `<F15>` is that it very rarely means anything and is generally ignored; `<Ctrl>`, however, _is_ meaningful, and when triggered at the wrong time could cause unintended behavior.

Comment: @Ruslan the OS is configured by the IT department to lock after a period of inactivity; running Caffeine allows me to bypass that, as long as I manually lock my machines when stepping away from my desk. Further, I don't have the source code for Caffeine, so I can't alter it.

Comment: Why doesn't it just simulate that event you get when you tap the touchpad when tapping isn't enabled, but it still focuses the window you're over - but over the current window so it doesn't do anything?

Comment: @Random832 that's a good question; I didn't write the program, so I don't know the logic behind choosing `<F15>` other than what's posted on the site.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can map a key to `<nop>` (short for "no operation") to make it "do nothing".

This should make Vim ignore the `<F15>` key in all modes:

```
:noremap <F15> <nop> 
:noremap! <F15> <nop>
```

This will *probably* fix your problem, but I haven't tested it in your specific situation, as I don't have various Windows/OSX machines with Caffeine  installed standing by  :-)

Comment: It looks like that did it! Thank you for your help.

Comment: It should be noted that presumably dead keys like `<f15>` are often used when  [Mapping fast keycodes in terminal Vim](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_fast_keycodes_in_terminal_Vim). Example of a plugin that does such a thing is [rsi.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rsi).

Comment: I've tried the following to keep Vim and Caffeine working together while Caffeine is active. None of these work. My caffeine is sending the F15 key, which is ^[[28~
`noremap <F15> <nop>
noremap! <F15> <nop>
noremap <^[[28~> <nop>
noremap! <^[[28~> <nop>
nnoremap <F15> <nop>
nnoremap <^[[28~> <nop>`
any ideas?

Comment: You can try binding the "raw key code" as `noremap <Esc>[28~ <nop>` @rem45acp; that `^[` is the escape character, and you need to either use `<Esc>` or type a literal escape character (by pressing `<C-v>` and then the escape key; but just using `<Esc>` is easier). You also don't use `<..>` for raw key codes like that.

Comment: @MartinTournoij I can confirm this works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer (and suggestions in the comments) didn't work for me, I opted for switching to MouseJiggler instead of Caffeine and the F15 problem is no more!

https://github.com/arkane-systems/mousejiggler

(I am not the author or anything, I honestly just looked around for something else and found that this really solved my problem well)